# Button height & programmical setTitle & Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I use autolayout.
On a screen I have one button + one imageview.
Between this element I set vertical space = 10

---

### | button  |

```
|
10
```

### |

### | image   |

If I setTitle of button with long text button overlap on image.
How to fix this problem?

**EDIT:**

Left image as it look now - right as I want that it to be:

[image]

This is my constraints:

[image]

This is my code:

```
btnFullLic2.setTitle(getLoc("FULL_VER_DESC"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btnFullLic2.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    btnFullLic2.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    btnFullLic2.titleLabel?.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Added OP's pictures in the post for better understanding of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either give maximum height to button or minimum height to image or both depending on your requirement. Adding maximum height constraint to button, will keep the button height from not going beyond that value. While giving minimum height to image, it will have minimum height and overlap the button if it increases.

Hope you understood the concept and get desired result..

Comment: OK Simply add a height constraint to your button, then double click the height constraint and change relation "Equal" to "Less than or equal to" and change the value of constant accordingly.. It will fix the maximum height of button and clip the rest of text to word wrap. Try it...

Comment: No it can't help. Because The behavior should be next. When button has a long title, height of button should increase and horizontal line should move down that vertical space = 10. But now when I change a title of button in program - button increase own height but autolayout doesn't work...